# How to get multiple values from Pandas dataframe whose indices and columns are known?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
>> pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[7,8,9]})

     A   B   C  
0    1   4   7  
1    2   5   8  
2    3   6   9
```

I want to select values `1,6,8` that correspond to index-column pairs `(0,'A'),(2,'B'),(1,'C')`. How do I simultaneously select them?

Comment: You should "lookup" this problem a little more thoroughly next time ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[7,8,9]})

rows, cols = zip(*[(0,'A'),(2,'B'),(1,'C')])

result = df.lookup(rows, cols)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1 6 8]
```

Comment: Probably mostly a matter of taste... but in cases like this, I find it useful to keep `idx = [(0,'A'),(2,'B'),(1,'C')]` or something around so it can be referred to or mutated later and re-used, then just inline it to lookup, so you can then just do a general, `result = df.lookup(*zip(*idx))`...